# How to get ggplot Heatmap (R) to use two colors? One for between a fill value of -.1 to .1 and one for not

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

How to get ggplot Heatmap (R) to use two colors? One for between a fill value of -.1 to .1 and one for not

```
 ggplot(base, aes(x,y, fill= base$`Equal Opportunity Difference`)) + 
        geom_tile() +
        #axis formatting
        scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40 , 50, 60, 70, 80, 90),
                       labels = c("10%", "20%","30%", "40%","50%", "60%", "70%","80%", "90%"),
                       limits = c(10,90)) +
        scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40 , 50, 60, 70, 80, 90),
                       labels = c("10%", "20%","30%", "40%","50%", "60%", "70%","80%", "90%"),
                       limits = c(10,90)) +
    
        geom_text(aes(label = signif(base$`Equal Opportunity Difference`,2)), color = "white", 
        size = 4) +
        scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint=c(-.1, s.1), low="#B2182B", high="#2166AC")
```

This is what I have right now, which isn't working. Also the axis are only showing 10% and  90%

I would appreciate if someone had a solution for that too.

Answer (score 1):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to guess potential solutions to your problem. Is this what you're hoping to achieve? If not, what do you want to change?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

x <- seq(1:10)
y <- seq(1:10)
df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
df$z <- signif(c(runif(50, -10, 0), runif(50, 0, 10)), 2)
df$z_categorised <- cut(df$z, c(seq(-10, -1, 1), seq(1, 10, 1)))
palette_red_blue <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#B2182B","white", "#2166AC"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z_categorised)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = z)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = palette_red_blue(19)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
                     labels = percent_format(scale = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
                     labels = percent_format(scale = 10)) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>